# How do French people turn nouns into adjectives (of a sort)?

Tags: adjectifs, noms

I learn French and I enjoy learning about its intricacies, much like English.

I was wondering the other day - how do French people turn nouns into adjectives (when I say adjectives, they're not necessarily actual ones, but when done in English, people know what's being said).

For example, in English, if you want to describe a place as having a vibe related to students, you would say:

> This place has a **student-y** (or **studenty**) vibe.

This is similar to how one would say:

> The laundry smells a bit **doggy**.

(i.e. The laundry smells like dogs.)

TL;DR: English primarily forms a "semi-adjective" by adding "-y" to the end of a word.

So, do the French do something similar? If so, how is it done? Is it informal like in English?

Comment: The question seems to assume that French _do_ turn nouns into adjectives, like in English. Why should that be assumed? Not necessarily productive when learning another language :-)

Comment: @Frank Sorry for the confusion. No, I'm not assuming they do, I just want to know **if** they do, and if so, how. Such intricacies of language are interesting to learn.

Comment: bad example here. There's no need to turn `dog` into an adjective as one already exists in French. `Canin` (f. `Canine`) is the adjective for `chien`. And you could refer to such a flavor as "Une odeur canine".

Comment: @StephaneDelcroix I see what you're saying. I just quickly thought of one. There is indeed "canine" in English, but it's more specialised, so to speak. I think if you said "the laundry has a canine smell" you'd sound a little pretentious. Also, "canine" wouldn't work at the end of the sentence like "doggy" does.

Comment: also, canin/canine is actually an -ine postfix to the latin root `canis` for `dog`

Comment: I don't think it is as easy to generalise as in english. A studenty place could be translated as 'un endroit étudiant' or 'une place étudiante' for the feminine gender form. So for some words the adjective is the same as the noun, without the need to add a suffix.

Answer (score 10):

Short version: *-eux* might be the best candidate, as well as *-ique*, if you have to use an adjective construction instead of a paraphrase. Long version: read on. :)

---

#### Morphological derivation

Since knowing the technical name for a phenomenon always helps with research on it: this is a form of [morphological derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphological_derivation). French version of the article [here](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9rivation_lexicale).

A common derivational strategy is the one you've identified: suffixation.
This can be used to change the meaning or to change the part of speech. (For example, the English suffix *-ful* attaches nouns to form other nouns, even if it's not very productive now: *handful*, *mouthful*, etc. On the other hand, *-ize* can turn an adjective into a verb, e.g. *regularize* "make regular").

So now what remains is to find out which French suffixes turn nouns into adjectives, keeping in mind that no one affix can apply to every member of a class. After that, to identify which ones are still in active service and not just historical (many of them are remnants of Latin that are no longer productive). And perhaps finally to see which ones come out of native speakers' mouths the most often if you want to go for "naturalness". :)

---

#### Wiktionary suggestions

Wiktionary French suffix category [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:French_suffixes).

One very undernourished subcategory: [French adjective-forming suffixes](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:French_adjective-forming_suffixes).

This category includes only three: *-able*, *-ais*, *-if*.

A quick look at [French words suffixed with *-able*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:French_words_suffixed_with_-able) indicates that this suffix attaches to verbs and usually results in the meaning: "which can have [verb] done to it". So not quite what you want.

A similar look at [French words suffixed with *-ais/e*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:French_words_suffixed_with_-ais) makes it clear that while this is for nouns, it only creates [demonyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonym).

The best of these three for your question is definitely [French words suffixed with *-if/ive*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:French_words_suffixed_with_-if), where we see several nouns converted to adjectives, among them:

> sportif effectif substitutif craintif fautif

---

#### Many more suggestions

That subcategory, however, is far from exhaustive.

For example, it doesn't include the highly productive [*-ique*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:French_words_suffixed_with_-ique):

> dogmatique canonique amnésique algorithmique ionique golfique

It also lacks the common [*-eux/se*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:French_words_suffixed_with_-eux):

> goutteux pierreux poussiéreux globuleux honteux cuivreux

And the possibly extinct *[-al/e](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:French_words_suffixed_with_-al)*:

> régional architectural professoral parental dental

And of course the one English speakers borrowed from French and perhaps love more than the French themselves at this point: [*-esque*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:French_words_suffixed_with_-esque).

> titanesque livresque carnavalesque

It's also possible, though I don't think it's that common, to use past participle endings: *-é* and *-u* in particular. There are a bunch of words with this form that are nouns, especially *-é* (, though I suspect it's phonological coincidence with the actual suffix.

Looking through a few more of those suffixes from the higher-level Wikipedia category and checking the words formed from it would help build out this list.

---

#### Most natural choice

As for the second step, though, it's hard for me to tell which ones would come first to mind and attach most freely to a broad range of words the way *-y* does in casual English. It looks to me like *-ique* is a pretty clear winner in terms of number of derivatives, including obviously recent and off-the-cuff ones like [*jazzique*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jazzique#French). *Edit:* Frank suggests *-eux* as his suffixe préféré in the comments!

The problem, as you already noticed, is that many of these very common "derivations" don't feel like "actual words" and so won't show up in dictionaries or on lists like these. This is only really good for capturing the ones with a wide and long-lived acceptance.

If anyone has any suggestions, I'll happily add them to this answer. :)

---

#### Alternative ways to say the same thing

And then of course you have to consider other strategies than suffixes. For example, it might be easier to create a paraphrase than to come up with an instantly recognizable new adjective:

> Ça sent bon / mauvais / doux / frais (adj.)
>
> <strike>Ça sent **chiennique**</strike> ?
>
> Ça sent **le chien**

While anyone might recognize what you likely meant by "chiennique", the other tactic is more naturally French (at least as I was taught it).

*Edit:* Another strategy in casual speech is simply to let the noun stand, as you might do in English:

> There's a real "student" atmosphere.
>
> *Il y a une ambiance « étudiant ».*

Here the quotation marks or guillemets, which help to show the bit of extra emphasis you might give it when speaking aloud, serve to set the word apart — as if to acknowledge and "apologize" for the fact that it's not adapted to the sentence structure. Notice that *étudiant* doesn't have to agree as feminine.

*Edit:* As others have now pointed out, a common paraphrase is *de [noun]* "noun-like". This is a great example of the translation technique of [transposition](http://www.interproinc.com/blog/translation-techniques): when the same idea is best represented by different grammatical structures in two languages. Here *[adj]* becomes *[prep] [noun]*. There are many such equivalences that translators find very important for rendering the target language naturally.

---

#### Appendix: morphological typology

errantlinguist suggests in the comments that French is a more [analytic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphological_typology#Analytic_languages) than [synthetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphological_typology#Synthetic_languages) language. Analytic languages, like Mandarin, have lots of individual particles (perhaps words) that each carry a bit of the meaning, while synthetic languages build or "bake" meaning into one base. I just encountered a word in the Hebrew Bible this morning that demonstrates syntheticism very well: *w'hitzdaqtiu* "**and** (*w*) **I** (*ti*) **would** (choice of vowels) **do** (*hi*) **justice** (*tz-d-q*) **to him** (*u*)". Particularly with that "choice of vowels" contribution, you can't pull this apart into separate words in a meaningful way. Clearly English is more analytic than Hebrew since I needed seven English words to translate one Hebrew word!

One thing that makes it hard to tell the exact status of French, English, and other languages is the issue noted above: how to tell how "productive" the affixes are. Latin was a [fusional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphological_typology#Fusional_languages) language, which is a type of synthetic in which a lot of grammar information is given by particular "shapes" the word takes. So you'd think Latin derivatives like French would also be fusional, but they differ in how much that holds true, and in what areas of the language.

A French verb's form gives information about the tense and the subject, and as Wikipedia points out, there are "[45 different single-word forms of the same verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusional_language#Conjugation)"! But that's still not as many as there could be. Why? Because to the ear, a bunch of forms sound exactly alike, so French adds a separate word to tell you exactly which subject it is: the *je*, *tu*, *il*, *elle*, *on*, *ils*, *elles* forms all sound alike for many verbs, so you have to say which one you mean, and you may as well throw in *nous* and *vous* once you've adopted the practice of having a separate subject. By contrast, Spanish, as you might know, "bakes" that information into the verb, which has no silent letters, so you almost never need to mention *yo*, *tú*, *él*, etc. to know who's doing the verb. So French verbs are more analytic than Spanish ones.

That was inflection — different forms of the same word. What about derivation, where you make new words? Well, all Latinate languages are packed to the brim with derivative affixes, but many of them are there just because the words are inherited from Latin, and the processes that derived the words aren't active anymore. As was pointed out in a comment above, *canin* is *canis* + *-in*. But what was *canis* in Latin is *chien* in French — and no one will accept *chiennin*. So *canin*, even though it can be broken down and analyzed, doesn't represent what French does now. On the other hand, the prefix *re-* "do again" is still alive and kicking, and it forms amusing words like *[rebonjour](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rebonjour)* now and then.

So to sum up the relevant idea: there are a bunch of suffixes in French that clearly derive adjectives from nouns, as spelled out above. But telling which ones are still active and which ones are "dead" requires a look at (1) words formed recently, say the last 100 years, on these patterns, and (2) words formed on the fly that speakers would accept. If the commenters below are right, a French speaker today would be more ready to accept an **analytic** solution like *de [noun]* than a **synthetic** solution with a suffix for this sort of thing.

Of course, it's not 100% one way or the other (what is?), but it's something to think about. :)

Comment: For the second step, it's hopeless to look for a rule - because we don't even think about it, we don't go around thinking "hey, I have a noun, let's now turn into a _cool_ adjective ... let's see ... what suffix should I use?" ;-) For _jazz_, we would probably say _jazzy_, in fact. Maybe. Or we wouldn't try an adjective and use a periphrase. Just my $.02 :-)

Comment: I think the truth is, either we know an adjective, there is one in common usage, or we just go for a periphrase, and don't try to make up an adjective. I didn't even realize that there categories of suffixes to turn nouns into adjectives... usage takes over, I'm afraid.

Comment: Of course, j'ai upvoté, excellent answer!

Comment: Re-reading your post, it crossed my mind that I would have said that _-eux/se_ was the standard go-to construction. In the other thread today, we saw _bordureux_ from _bordure_, which although complete new slang with infinitesimal audience, shows that _-eux_ was chosen. Maybe not a great example, but they used _-eux_. I would probably have done the same: _bordurique_, _bordural_, borduresque_ ... : not quite. _bordureux_ might be "best" here.

Comment: Merci ! Incorporated.

Comment: It's not a hard and fast, of course :-)

Comment: Wow! This is a fantastic and very helpful answer - thank you! I particularly enjoyed this line: 'And of course the one English speakers borrowed from French and perhaps love more than the French themselves at this point: -esque.' @Frank On that note (pun intended), do French people/speakers suffix "-y" to French words like in "jazzy", or is it a rarity? Would an average French speaker understand "chienny", for example?

Comment: Going back to this answer, can I take from it that in general French speakers will tend to rephrase rather than "invent"? I really do like the French language, but it also goes to show how flexible and vast English can be.

Comment: @DogLover - not really, but for people who know English and want to be _branchés_, they might do that. I wouldn't say it's common. _Chienny_ doesn't work at all. It probably works for _jazzy_ (and _sexy_, by the way) because the words are "universally" known, and come from English.

Comment: @DogLover - In my personal opinion, I think that yes, we would tend to rephrase than create a new adjective. An easy way, for _chien_ for example, would be to say _**de** chien_: _temps de chien_ (bad weather). Actually, Luke, you could explore that _de_ construction in your answer to compensate for lack of an adjective corresponding to a noun. It is probably fairly common.

Comment: @Frank D'accord. Merci beaucoup!

Comment: @LukeSawczak - the more I think about it, the more I realize that this _de_ construction might be quite important. I can even substitute it in many cases : _forme globuleuse_ -> _en forme de globule_, _corps professoral_ -> _corps des professeurs_, _atmosphère carnavalesque_ -> _atmosphère de carnaval_.

Comment: @Frank yes, this is a perfectly valid phenomenon: French is a very [analytic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_language) language (even more so than English), which means that, even if you *can* perform morphological derivation, it's not something speakers are wont to do (or rather, it's analytic *because* speakers tend not to use morphological processes). Contrast this with e.g. Turkish, where [entire English sentences can be translated as a single word-like structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_word_in_Turkish#Word_formation).

Comment: @Frank Pardon the rather abstract example, but does that mean the most likely candidate for a phrase such as "peachy surprise" would be <<le surpris de pêche>>?

Comment: @DogLover "pêche" doesn't have the same slang meanings in French as "peach" does in English, but it does suggest to me another possible suffix: "u/ue". As in -> "il a la pêche" = "il est pêchu". That would be quite familiar though. Also the suffix will depend a lot on sonority and context; for example I think "eux/euse" would be more likely to be used in something pejorative.

Comment: And thanks, @errantlinguist. Added a probably highly redundant section on morphological typology for the keeners. :) Hope it checks out.

Comment: @DogLover - I don't think we have an expression with _peach_ that would work. This one (with the English meaning) might be English only :-)

Comment: @LukeSawczak - realized this morning that sometimes we just use the noun, as in _une ambiance étudiant_ rather than _une ambiance estudiantine_, which is grammatically possible, of course, and used, but just using the noun sounds less "high-brow" to me.

Comment: @Frank I was thinking the same thing when drafting this. It especially helps if you add the guillemets: *Une ambiance « étudiant ».* I'll incorporate this too into an already bloated answer. :p

Comment: Not _bloated answer_, but _reference answer_ :-) it's great collective work.

Comment: @LukeSawczak - maybe we also say _une ville étudiante_. Not necessarily correct from a grammatical point of view, of course, but it could be used in conversation.

Answer (score 4):

With both of your examples, the *[-in(e)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-ine)* suffix which comes from the prolific *-inus* Latin one, would work:

- étudiant → [estudiantin(e)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/estudiantin)
- chien → [canin(e)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/canin)

> This place has a student-y (or studenty) vibe.
>
> Il y a une ambiance estudiantine dans ce lieu.

It's harder to build a sentence with *canin* though, especially because of the clash with the *canine* tooth.

> The laundry smells a bit doggy.

I would venture:

> Le linge a une odeur un peu « canine… »

but a more idiomatic and colloquial sentence would be:

> Le linge sent un peu le chien mouillé.

This *-inus* suffix had several variants, *-anus*, *-enus*, *-ianus*, and *-unus*.

Here are some examples in *-in*, *-ain* and *-ien*:

- bœuf → bovin(e)
- cheval → chevalin(e)
- Christ → chrétien(e)
- cité → citadin(e)
- monde → mondain(e)
- dieu → divin(e)
- enfant → enfantin(e)
- femme → féminin(e)
- foire → forain(e)
- Gironde → girondin(e) and many other *gentilés* (Amérique → américain(e))
- homme → humain(e)
- liberté → libertin(e)
- mer → marin(e)
- mâle → masculin(e)
- monde → mondain(e)
- porc → porcin(e)
- sang → sanguin(e)
- taureau → taurin(e)
- éléphant → éléphantin(e)
- utérus → utérin(e)

Note that the root used in the French adjective is often closer to the Latin than the from used with the noun and *estudiantin* probably came to French from Spanish.

Comment: Thank you for the answer (and also for the references to my examples). I suppose that this leads onto another question though - how common would adopting the Latin root and adding "-in(e)" be in French? Not so much with codified words such as "masculin" but possibly in a spoken or informal context.

Comment: For neologisms, there is no single rule. That would depend a lot on the word you want to "convert" to an adjective and should take into account the fact French is much more prone to use *de* than English use *of*.

Comment: For _Il y a une ambiance estudiantine dans ce lieu._, which sounds a bit high-brow, we might say _Il ya une ambiance étudiant_: just using the unmodified noun as an adjective. It's possible sometimes. Another alternative alongside the _de_ construction.

Comment: _Le linge a une odeur un peu « canine… »_ is grammatically possible, but probably not heard. I would be really, really surprised. _Ca sent le chien_ would be more common.

Comment: @Frank *Ambiance estudiantine* is not 9-3 slang but not necessarily eye-brow either. It seems also to be slightly more popular than *ambiance étudiant* which is otherwise fine. I was very aware about the issue with *canine* and stated it. *Une odeur porcine* while still rare, would have worked better. My point was more that the process to coin adjectives from names has always existed in French (and before in Latin) so it might not be necessary to try doing it again when they already exist. Should we always use these existing adjectives the way English does? Of course not.

Comment: "9-3 slang"? What is that?

Comment: @Frank ***Ç**a sent le chien* is somewhat rude. A softer and more common expression is *ça sent le chien mouillé*.

Comment: @Frank http://www.bondyblog.fr/200601171219/parlez-vous-le-neuf-trois-93/#.WL79ljvyvDc

Comment: Oui, j'ai failli ajouter _mouillé_, puis je me suis dit que ça changeait trop le sens. Personnellement, je ne perçois pas nécessairement la nuance impolie, surtout s'il ne s'agit pas d'une personne.

Comment: Bondy est un anti Auteuil-Neuilly-Passy? Intéressant.

Comment: @Frank Genre … https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/9-3

Comment: Est-ce que c'est encore du français ou une langue dérivée? Comment décide-t-on qu'on à faire à une nouvelle langue?

Comment: @Frank C'est du Latin qui continue à évoluer…

Comment: On pourrait dire ça... et même remonter à une _Ursprache_ indo-européenne hypothétique qui continue à évoluer. M'enfin bon, appeler le 9-3 du Latin... ;-)