# Origine de la différence de prononciation du "-ent"

Tags: prononciation, histoire, linguistique, latin, évolution

Dans la phrase,

> Les poules du couvent couvent.

Les homonymes "couvent" n'ont pas la même prononciation. Même si ces deux mots n'ont pas la même origine latine, pourquoi existe-t-il une différence au niveau de la prononciation de "ent"? Et pourquoi le "ent" est "muet" seulement lorsqu'il s'agit de la forme conjuguée à la 3ème personne du pluriel au présent?

EDIT: Je sais faire la différence entre les deux, mais je souhaite savoir **pourquoi** il y a une différence.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You already know the synchronic side of things — the rule for how to use it today: the *-ent* on 3rd-person plural verbs is silent, and on most if not all other words it's pronounced. (Note that it's not only in the present that it's silent, but many 3rd-person plural paradigms, e.g. *furent*, *étaient*, *seraient*.)

On the diachronic side, the history of how it *came* to be the rule, the explanation has to do with Latin stress patterns.

---

#### Latin stress patterns

Latin stress generally fell on either the penultimate syllable, if it was a long vowel, or else the syllable before the penultimate ("antépénultime" selon certaines grammaires) if the penultimate syllable's vowel was short. Gradually, in French, everything but the syllable that was stressed in Latin disappeared, "eroded" away by a lack of emphasis — which is why the last syllable is always stressed in French: the stressed syllable is the one that was strong enough to survive! (Of course, sometimes the vestige of a following syllable is preserved in the form of an *e muet* and/or silent consonants.)

Thus Auguste Brachet in his *Nouvelle grammaire française fondée sur l'histoire de la langue*, [§ 51](https://books.google.ca/books?id=cAMTAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA32#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> En français la syllabe accentuée est toujours la dernière syllabe [...] le français a conservé l'accent tonique sur la syllabe qu il occupait en latin et il dit *finír*, *aimér* *labeúr*, en élevant la voix sur les mêmes syllabes que les Romains.
>
> Quand, au lieu d'être longue, l'avant-dernière syllabe latine était brève [...] le français a été obligé de resserrer violemment ces mots latins en supprimant toutes les voyelles qui suivaient en latin la syllabe accentuée.

---

#### Latin stress in conjugation paradigms

Brachet goes on to apply this system to our friend *-ent* in [§ 264](https://books.google.ca/books?id=cAMTAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA113&lpg=PA113#v=onepage&q&f=false), quoted in full here:

> Notons aussi que *ent* (*ils chant*-**ent**, *finiss*-**ent**, *rend*-**ent**) est muet dans ces terminaisons verbales, au lieu d'être sonore et accentué (comme dans *souv*-**ent**, *auv*-**ent**, *arg*-**ent**).
>
> *Chant*-**ons**, *chant*-**ez**, *chant*-**ent** viennent du latin *cant*-**amus**, *cant*-**atis**, *cant*-**ant**. Une fois ces trois finales créées pour la première conjugaison, le français les a employées pour former le pluriel de nos autres conjugaisons, sans recourir pour ces dernières aux formes des conjugaisons latines correspondantes.
>
> *Ent* est toujours muet dans les terminaisons plurielles des verbes, parce qu'en latin *ant* (am-*ant*) était de même inaccuentué, et comme nous l'avons vu § 51, toute voyelle latine inaccentuée, à la fin du mot, devient muette ou disparaît.
>
> *[extra hyphens inserted to cope with SE finickiness about italics and bolding]*

---

#### Seemingly inconsistent treatment of -ent

The question that arises and that you seem to be asking is: okay, sounds good. So why did all the other *-ent*s remain pronounced?

The answer is that they were the stressed syllable in their respective words. According to the rules for Latin stress just described, this means that the *ent* was not the final syllable in Latin:

> *convéntum* "(un) couvent", *subínde* "souvent", *argéntum* "argent"

(Interestingly enough, "auvent" is from a Gaulish root, conformed to the Latin model by analogy.)

Hence the rule applied consistently: these were cut to their last syllable and so were the verbal forms.

---

#### Maintaining distinctions

You might also wonder why, if we're just cutting words to their final syllables, we end up with *-ons* and *-ez* for the *nous* and *vous* forms respectively. After all, if *a* is the last stressed syllable in *cantámus* and *cantátis*, shouldn't both those forms end in *-a* today?

The answer is that with these conjugations in particular, but also with some other words, the final consonants sometimes survived, or an intervening unstressed syllable was deleted or merged instead. There is a good motivation for this process, stated by Camille Chabaneau in *Histoire et théorie de la conjugaison française* at the end of [a longer footnote on these conjugations](https://books.google.ca/books?id=N4o-AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA46):

> C'est à un besoin analogue, remarquons-le en terminant, celui d'avoir partout des flexions distinctes et sensibles, que les patois obéissent [...]

And it's not only les patois that need to give clear information about the subject of a verb!

This is interesting because, as discussed in [another answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24978/how-do-french-people-turn-nouns-into-adjectives-of-a-sort/24979#24979), despite hanging on to *-ons* and *-ez* at this stage instead of what would have been the identical *-a* for most inflections, French ultimately gave up its dependence on verbal inflections to distinguish the subject and opted instead for separate subject pronouns: *je*, *tu*, *il*, etc., optional in other Romance languages.

---

#### The four irregular forms

As an appendix, there are a few odd cases to look at: *vont*, *font*, *sont*, *ont*. How did these end up becoming monosyllabic, with the *-ant* surviving in the form of *-ont* and becoming stressed?

Probably for the same reason as above: the need to distinguish them. Here are the Latin forms:

> [*vādunt*](http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/go.php?D1=9&H1=109&T1=vado) "vont"
>
>  [*habent*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Annexe:Conjugaison_en_latin/habeo) "ont"
>
>  [*faciunt*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Annexe:Conjugaison_en_latin/facio) "font"
>
>  [*sunt*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Annexe:Conjugaison_en_latin/sum) "sont"

Except for *sunt*, if these forms were cut off at the stressed syllable, they would end in that *-a* that is so useless for distinguishing the inflection from, say, the 3rd-person singular form. Thus, like *nous* and *vous*, those final consonants hang on a little tighter.

(As sumelic shares below via [this community wiki answer](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/19257/latin-to-french-evolution-of-certain-forms-of-facere-faire/19453#19453), in fact, the vowel of the final unstressed syllable also survived in *vādunt*, *habent*, and *faciunt*, which were supposed to have included the post-deletion sequence *a_u* in popular speech. This diphthong /au/ monophthongized to /o/ in French, the spelling here reflecting that change. The final form of *sunt* "sont" seems to have arisen by a different vowel shift.)

---

#### Aside on Internet resources

Incidentally, an amusing analysis of verb radicals that I happened on in [this Wiktionary annexe article](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Annexe:Conjugaison_en_fran%C3%A7ais/Pr%C3%A9sent_de_l%E2%80%99indicatif#Pourquoi_des_radicaux_diff.C3.A9rents_.3F), which you may freely ignore since it's utter BS:

> Il n’y a aucune raison logique, sinon que les formes conservées jusqu’à aujourd'hui sont toujours celles qui se prononcent le plus facilement.

Whereas here's a surprising gem in a [WordReference forum post](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/pourquoi-la-terminaison-verbale-ent-ne-se-prononce-pas.1620397/#post-8138162) by a well-informed person!

Comment: The explaination of the "o" that I read somewhere was that it comes, at least in "vont," from syneresis; the diphthong "au" > "o"

Comment: @sumelic Thanks for that précision; it makes sense in light of that change across much of French. Of course, if that's the explanation, then *vādunt* and *faciunt* yield the modern words as expected while *habent* and even *sunt* would have been corrected by analogy!

Comment: I found where I read the explanation; on the page that Laure linked to in a comment on the following Linguistics question: [Latin to French - evolution of certain forms of “FACERE > faire”](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/19257)

Comment: @sumelic Thank you! Edited to reflect that answer.

Comment: I'm not certain, but I think Latin "sunt" > French "sont" is regular, not analogical. From what I understand, the development would have been as follows: in Vulgar Latin, Classical Latin short "u" became close "o". /sont/. (We can see this vowel in Spanish "son" or Italian "sono.") From Vulgar Latin to Old French, /o/ in many environments developed to /u/, which was often written with the letter "o" (e.g. Latin *operarius* > OF *ovrier* > modern French *ouvrier*). Before a nasal, the vowel was nasalized as usual for French...

Comment: and at some point there were some sound changes lowering nasal vowels in French. (For example, "en" became /ɑ̃/ in words like *vendre,* /ĩ/ became /ɛ̃/ in *divin*; it seems that likewise /ũ/ was lowered to /ɔ̃/.) So overall there would be Latin /sunt/ > VL /sont/ > OF /sunt/ and then some other changes of consonant loss and nasal vowel lowering that I don't know the order of that regularly produce modern French /sɔ̃(t)/.

Comment: @sumelic Ah, all right. :) It's been too long since my Romance linguistics course that traced all those shifts. Thanks for being thorough; edited to avoid recourse to analogy.

Comment: @sumelic Both mid vowels series merged before nasals in Old French (and afaik all the oil languages), so *sont* never had the time to rise to /sunt/

Comment: As a note of interest re: the generalisation of the /õ/ ending to several irregular verbs, there are still modern French variants (in Louisiana and Acadia) that use it as 3PL suffix for every verbs, i.e. "ils aimont"

Comment: @Eauquidort: Maybe it depends on the dialect/language. The /aʊ/ diphthong in English "count/mountain/fount" seems to point to /ũ/ in Anglo-French at least; I found this described in "From Latin to Modern French with Especial Consideration of Anglo-Norman" by Mildred Katharine Pope, although perhaps there is an error in this source (link to Google Books in my answer on the following page: [Why do “bomb” and “tomb” have different pronunciations?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/320512/why-do-bomb-and-tomb-have-different-pronunciations/322076#322076))

Comment: @Eauquidort: There seems to be info on the evidence for a high back vowel before nasal consonants on Pope p. 169, if you can view it: https://books.google.com/books?id=K9JRAQAAIAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q=The%20complete%20nasalization%20of%20the%20vowels%20and%20diphthongs%20appears%20to%20have%20been%20a%20slow%20process&f=false Apparently there are assonance patterns that indicate this (as well as some spelling evidence like "num" = "nom").