# Formation of adjectives by means of freely productive suffixes? (Banana-y, monkey-ish, etc)

Tags: traduction, langage-informel

My question is, supposing you know about that sort of freely productive suffix formation of adjectives we use in English, mostly '-y' or '-ish', 'how would you make new words like that in French?'. 
For example: “It has sort of a raspberry-y, coffee-y taste?”

The choice of appending one of those two suffixes is left to the speaker and he/she can do that with really any noun (such adjectives, then, are not found in the dictionaries). I was wondering if something like that is possible in French?

Comment: [See this thread](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24978) for a start.

Comment: I would use comme x for all of them, myself.  No would say: coffee-y, it would be coffee-ish. And in English, y or ish means like. So comme works fine. It can also be plutôt. It depends on the word, the function and the context.

Answer (score 3):

There are various suffixes; however, they are not appended freely, bar exceptions (**-issime**); for instance you can say "largeot" but not "fortot" or "fortet", whereas there is no problem with "fortissime". Here are some of the most important ones, with a few  instances of words in which they occur ;

- "**-eux**" is usually derogatory; it's used with nouns;
  farineux, pâteux, sirupeux, anguleux, véreux, …
- "**-ard**" is also derogatory;  it's used with nouns;
  revanchard, cabochard, paillard, pantouflard, pochard, poissard, roublard, débrouillard, …
- "**-et**" connotes smallness, and what can deemed puny as well; ((TLFi) éventuellement avec une valeur péjorative, laudative ou hypocoristique (qui exprime une intention caressante, affectueuse, notamment dans le langage des enfants ou ses imitations)); it's used with adjectives and nouns;
  (*adjectives*) jaunet,  trist**ouillet**, finet, …
- "**-ot**" (TLFi) Suff. formateur de subst. et d'adj. auxquels il donne le plus souvent une valeur diminutive.
  (*adjectives*) ballot, largeot, vieillot, …
- ''**-esque**'' (TLFi) [Le mot de base est un adj. qualificatif exprimant souvent une qualité originale ou bizarre que le suff. vient accentuer sinon caricaturer]  can be used rather freely
  (*adjectives*) dévorantesque, maboulesque, magiquesque, sauvagesque
  (ajouté après une remarque par **user Loïc Di Benedetto**)
- "**-ien**" ([TLFi](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/36302/formation-of-adjectives-by-means-of-freely-productive-suffixes-banana-y-monke/36308?noredirect=1#comment95290_36308)) B. − [Formateur d'adj. à partir de noms propres de pers. (notamment des personnalités du monde artist., littér., pol. ou sc.), avec le sens de « relatif à, qui a rapport à; qui tient de »] V. apollinarien, aristotélicien, baudelairien, cicéronien, giralducien, jupitérien, kafkaïen, luthérien, mallarméen, sadien, victorien, etc.
  **Remarque**  2. Le suff. -ien est toujours productif dans la lang. mod. et Dub. Dér. 1962, p. 110 comparant deux éd. de Pt Lar. (1906 et 1960) constate que, pour la lettre A, les dér. en -ien ajoutés dépassent en nombre ceux qui sont retranchés et note une grande stabilité des dér. anc. Le suff. a été très productif au XIXème siècle. et il le reste au XXème siècle surtout pour les dér. formés à partir de noms de pers. et pour les noms d'agents, l'apparition de sc. et de techn. nouv. lui offrant un large champ d'emploi. (ajouté après une remarque par **user Xoudo**)
- "**-issime**" (from the Italian suffix "-issimo") can be used rather freely;
  (*adjectives*) élégantissime, énormissime, faiblissime, longuissime, louchissime, pâlissime, radicalissime, grandissime, …
  (*proper nouns*) béjartissime, godardissime, josephissime, …

Comment: Il manque le suffixe -esque, un peu desuet

Comment: Avec les noms propres, on a aussi beaucoup les "ien" : *hitchcockien*, mais aussi "chiraquien", "sarkozien"

Comment: y and ish veulent dire comme (like) en anglais. This tastes chocolate-y. = This tastes like chocolate. Cela a un gout comme le café.

Comment: @Lambie I know that, but in French there is no equivalent. One can think analogically and say "chocolateux", but this practice does not exist. That use of this prefix exist but it is not freely usable: for instance "suiffeux", "sulfureux", "aqueux" are extant forms, … and then there  can be  two meanings ("qui rappelle l'eau", "qui contient de l'eau" (solution aqueuse)).

Comment: On ne traduit "par équivalence". On traduit par le/un sens. Et pour le sens, il faut des exemples précis.

Comment: @Lambie Il ne s'agit pas là de traduction mais de création d'une forme qui n'existe pas encore.  "y" dans "snow → snowy" is equivalent to "eux" dans "neige → neigeux", pour ainsi dire.

Comment: Ah, mais snowy est un terme officiel.  Comme rainy (pluvieux) Il ne s'agit pas de mots terminant en y. Il s'agit d'ajouter -y à un mot qui ne l'a pas.  Pas du tout pareil.  The cake tasted yolk-y. = like egg yolks.

Comment: Jacoballens, beware of the suggestion made in a previous comment *cela a un goût comme le café*. Using *cela* instead of *ça* wouldn't be used here by a native speaker and *avoir un goût comme le café*  doesn't mean *taste like coffee* but *taste something like the coffee taste something*. There is no requirement for both tastes to match...

Comment: @Lambie > Je peux m'imaginer, dans certains cas, "inventer" un terme dans un registre familier sur base de l'un de ces suffixes: "Ce gateau a un gout jaune d'oeuf-esque, beurresque, chocolateux"

Comment: @LaurentS. Bien sûr, mais les termes buttery and chocalatey et eggy existent en soi. :)

Answer (score 2):

Native French speakers wouldn't try to use any suffix here.

A common way to express it would be:

> *Ça a un goût **genre framboise-café**.*

[Here is an example](https://www.vice.com/fr/article/qbyjaq/suck-this-v2n2) of such an expression:

> J’utilise tellement de goûts différents que je ne peux pas en faire la liste. Mes préférés, ce sont les Trident Splash, durs à l’extérieur et mous à l’intérieur, avec **un goût genre framboise-pomme**.

The [original English text](https://www.vice.com/en/article/3bk95j/suck-this-v15n1) doesn't use -y or -ish suffixes but I believe the meaning is similar:

> I use so many different flavors of gum that I can’t even begin to list them. I shop around. My favorites are these ones called Trident Splash that have a hard shell with a gummy core and it’ll be like **a raspberry-apple flavor or something**.

Another one where *genre* is used the same way:

> J'aimerais faire installer sur ma voiture qui est noire deux bandes rouges qui traversent du coffre au capot avant. **Genre voiture de course**. Bref ma voiture est neuve et je me demandais si ce genre d'auto collant, j'ai été voir une cie de St Jerome qui fait ça, si ça abimait la peinture si un jour je devais les enlever.

That seems a context where "**racecarish**" would work.

For actual suffix use in French, see [How do French people turn nouns into adjectives (of a sort)?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24978)